# The Mean Value Theorem ( Increasing at point)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

As I go over some important topics in Calculus (by Salas), he stated such a theorem;

> "Suppose that $\ f(x)\ $ differentiable at $\ x=c,\ $ if $\ f'(c)>0,\ $ then
>
> $f (c − h) < f (c) < f (c + h)\ $
> for all positive $\ h\ $ sufficiently small. "

But some times we cannot find such "$\ h\ $" at some point even though the derivative there is positive; ex.

$f(x)=$\begin{cases}x+2x^2sin(1/x) & x\neq\ 0\\ 0 & x=\ 0 \\ \end{cases}
the derivative at $\ 0\ $ equals $\ 1 $; however, it is not possible to find any open interval around zero satisfies the condition since the derivative values fluctuate between negative and positive about zero, this condition satisfies only if the function is increasing at some point. So, did I make a mistake and what is the correct understanding?

Comment: $f(x) = x(1+2x\sin(1/x))$ *is* positive for small $x > 0$, and negative for small $x < 0$.

Comment: Why do you think that the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is $1$?

Comment: Yes the derivative of that function fluctuates around $c=0$. But this is irrelevant. What is relevant is that for any $\ h>0,\ f(c-h)<f(c)<f(c+h)\ $, that is, $\ f\ $ is increasing *at the point* $\ c=0$.

Comment: @aexl the derivative at x=0 equal 1!!

Comment: @AdamRubinson Robert Bartle stated in his book (Introduction to Real Analysis) that increasing at some point implies the function should be increasing on some neighborhood of the point, he mentioned this example and said that thi function is neither decreasing or increasing at 0!!!

Comment: "Robert Bartle stated in his book (Introduction to Real Analysis) that increasing at some point implies the function should be increasing on some neighborhood of the point". Then I think Robert Bartle is wrong, and your function is a counter-example. Unless he has a non-standard definition of "increasing at a point"?

Comment: @AdamRubinson As I remember Stephen Abbott (Understanding Analysis) mentioned same definition on the exercises, same thing with Kenneth A.Ross (Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus) I think in some exercise has asked to prove that some particular function is not increasing nor decreasing at 0, despite the derivative there is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that $f$ is not increasing or decreasing in any interval containing the origin, but that is not what the theorem claims.

We can verify the conclusion of the theorem in this case directly: For $0 < |x| < 1/2$ is
$$
 1+2x \sin(1/x) \ge 1-2|x| > 0 \, ,
$$
so that $f(-h) < f(0) < f(h)$ for $0 < h < 1/2$.

In other words: For fixed $c$ are

> $f(c-h) < f(c) < f(c+h)$ for sufficiently small positive $h$.

and

> $f$ is increasing on $[c-h, c+h]$ for sufficiently small positive $h$.

different statements. The former holds if $f'(c) > 0$, but not necessarily the latter.

Comment: Where does $1+2x \sin(1/x)$ come from?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: From $f(x) = x(1+2x\sin(1/x))$. The second factor is positive for small non-zero $x$, and then has $f(x)$ the same sign as $x$.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: thank you a lot, that seems precisely. But still have small note if you don't mind about second conclusion that "f is increasing", I think the inequality is not so far right since for all "h" you'll find δ such that δ<h and f(c+δ) has negative derivative which implies by same theorem, you should find a neighborhood about f(c+δ) satisfies the flip of the inequality; f((c+δ)-ξ)>f(c+δ)>f((c+δ)+ξ) ∧ f((c+δ)-ξ),f(c+δ),f((c+δ)+ξ) ∈ [c-h,c+h] ; ξ is positive arbitrary small number, which means f(x) is not so far increasing on the interval [c-h,c+h].

Comment: @HumamKh.: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. The theorem does *not* claim that $f$ is increasing near $c$. It only claims that $f(x) < f(c)$ in some interval $x \in (c-h, h)$ and $f(x) > f(c)$ in some interval $x \in (c, c+h)$.

Comment: @MartinR , Everything is alright, I was just wondering about your conclusion above "f is increasing on [c-h,c+h] for sufficiently small positive small h. " which I think seems contradict with theorem but you re-answered me and said "The theorem does not claim that f is increasing near c.". Now I think I understand the theorem in the right way. Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: @MartinR Last thing I want to be sure with it, your conclusion above that "f is increasing on [c-h,c+h]" because you re-answered me that it's not increasing. It only claims that f(x)<f(c) in some interval x∈(c−h,c) and f(x)>f(c) in some interval x∈(c,c+h). Thank you for cooperation.

Comment: @HumamKh.: That is correct. As I tried to explain in the answer, the first statement is true, but the second statement can be false (as your example demonstrates).